# Compiletime check if there are two template instantiations with identical template-parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

If I have two unrelated templates `A`  and `B`, how do I perform a compiletime check to see if there are two identical parametrations. E.g. if I have some parameter type `P1` and `P2`, I want to let the client to instantiate `A<P1>` and `B<P2>` but not `A<P1>` and `B<P1>`.

I have a solution to this using a variadic template `Checker<typename... Xx>` that one has to instatiate with the templates in question:

```
using a = A<P1>;
using b = B<P1>;
using checker = Checker<a, b>;

checker::init(); // can be empty
                 // static_assert fails here
```

This works if every parameter typ has a unique id (mask) and therefore I can OR all the masks and see if the number of ones is equal to the size of the parameter pack of `Checker`.

This solution is not good because a client can *forget* to instatiate the `Checker` template.

I wonder if this check can be made somewhat more under the hood?

Comment: What if A or B has more then one parameter? Does order of parameters matter?

Comment: Maybe they have more than one parameter, but the relevant parameter will be e.g. the first one.

Comment: Are you able to modify `A` and `B` to do the checking internally?

Comment: Yes. I could modify them. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This solution is not good because a client can forget to instatiate the `Checker` template.

Good intuition - you should therefore prevent the client from instantiating `A` and `B` before instantiating `Checker`. You can achieve this by providing them  as *type aliases* accessible from `Checker` only.

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T> struct A;
    template <typename T> struct B;
}

template <typename P0, typename P1>
struct Checker
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<P0, P1>);

    using A = detail::A<P0>;
    using B = detail::B<P1>;
};
```

Usage:

```
using ClientABProvider = ABProvider<foo, bar>;
using A = typename ClientABProvider::A;
using B = typename ClientABProvider::B;
```

```
using ClientABProvider = ABProvider<foo, foo>; // Error!
using A = typename ClientABProvider::A;
using B = typename ClientABProvider::B;
```

---

If you want `A` and `B` to be user-provided, you can have `Checker`'s type aliases be templates - but this kind of defeats its purpose since the user has already access to `A` and `B` in the first place.

```
template <typename P0, typename P1>
struct Checker
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<P0, P1>);

    template <template <typename> class XA>
    using A = XA<P0>;

    template <template <typename> class XB>
    using B = XB<P1>;
};
```

Comment: Indeed the templates `A` and `B` are user-provided. So this solution isn't better than my original.

Comment: @wimalopaan: if that's the case then the user can always instantiate them wherever he/she wants. Are you using `A` and `B` in your code? Make the  code that uses them only accessible through `Checker` to the user.